# Execute a form after System.exit (0);

Tags: java, jframe

I'm trying to close all open forms with System.exit (0); And then call the loggin but I close the execution of the program.
Is there any way to close everything and then call the loggin?

Pd: translated with google translator xD

regards

```
 private void cerrarSesion() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se cerrara el sistema", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, warning);
    System.exit(0);
    frmLoggin lo = new frmLoggin();
    lo.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: [System.exit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit) will terminate the currect JVM so anything after the `System.exit` wont be executed.

Comment: Another method I can use to close all open forms?

Comment: Either don't use System.exit or close all forms before System.exit

Comment: By somehow keeping track of them! To then close them one by one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually keep track of all "forms" in a list somewhere, then just iterate over that list and close them.

If for whatever reason this is not possible you *could* use JFrame.getWindows() which accesses all Windows in the application

```
for (Window each : JFrame.getWindows()) {
    each.setVisible(false);
}
```

Note: This may not properly shutdown the forms, e.g. remove listeners/stop threads the forms may be using...

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me.
Same as other thanks for responding